# Is there a quicker way to evaluate the following definite integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate the following definite integral $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x}{(x^2+x+4)\sqrt{4x^2+4x+5}}\,dx.$$

---

### **My steps:**

Separating the integral gives
$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{8x+4}{8(x^2+x+4)\sqrt{4x^2+4x+5}}-\frac1{2(x^2+x+4)\sqrt{4x^2+4x+5}}\right)dx.$$
For the first integral, letting $$u=\sqrt{4x^2+4x+5}$$
$$du=\frac{8x+4}{2\sqrt{4x^2+4x+5}}\ dx$$
gives
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{8x+4}{8(x^2+x+4)\sqrt{4x^2+4x+5}}\ dx = \frac14\int_{\sqrt5}^{\sqrt{13}} \frac1{x^2+x+4}du$$
$$$$Knowing that $$x^2+x+4=\frac{u^2+11}4$$
The integral in terms of $u$ becomes:
$$\int_{\sqrt5}^{\sqrt{13}}\frac1{u^2+11}\ du=\frac{\sqrt{11}}{11}\int_{\sqrt5}^{\sqrt{13}}\frac1{\sqrt{11}\left(\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{11}}\right)^2+1\right)}\,du$$
Evaluating the indefinite integral, we get:
$$\frac1{\sqrt{11}}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{4x^2+4x+5}{11}}\right)+C$$
For the second integral, let:$$u=\frac{8x+4}{\sqrt{4x^2+4x+5}}$$ $$du=\frac{32}{\sqrt{(4x^2+4x+5)^3}}\ dx$$
Thus: $$-\int_0^1\frac1{2(x^2+x+4)\sqrt{4x^2+4x+5}}\,dx=-\frac1{64}\int_{4/\sqrt5}^{12/\sqrt{13}}\frac{4x^2+4x+5}{x^2+x+4}\,du$$
To write the integrand in terms of $u$, we need to find values for $a$ and $b$ such that:
$$\frac{x^2+x+4}{4x^2+4x+5}=a\cdot u^2+b\Leftrightarrow\frac{x^2+x+4}{4x^2+4x+5}=a\cdot\frac{64x^2+64x+16}{4x^2+4x+5}+b\cdot\frac{4x^2+4x+5}{4x^2+4x+5}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow x^2+x+4=(64a+4b)x^2+(64a+4b)x+(16a+5b)$$
$$$$By solving a system of linear equations for $a$ and $b$ for the relations:
$$\begin{cases}
64a+4b=1 \\
16a+5b=4
\end{cases}$$
we find that: $$ a=-\frac{11}{256}\quad \wedge  \quad b=\frac{15}{16}.$$
Therefore, the integral in terms of $u$ becomes:
$$-\frac1{64}\int_{4/\sqrt5}^{12/\sqrt{13}}\frac{4x^2+4x+5}{x^2+x+4}\ du=-4\int_{4/\sqrt5}^{12/\sqrt{13}}\frac{1}{240-11u^2}\,du=$$
$$=-\frac1{60}\int_{4/\sqrt5}^{12/\sqrt{13}}\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{\sqrt{11}u}{4\sqrt{15}}\right)^2}\,du$$
Letting: $$s=\frac{\sqrt{11}}{4\sqrt{15}}u$$ $$ds=\frac{\sqrt{11}}{4\sqrt{15}}du$$
and subsequently substituting for $s$, obtaining:
$$\displaystyle-\frac1{\sqrt{165}}\int_{\sqrt{11/75}}^{\sqrt{33/65}}\frac{1}{1-s^2}\ ds$$
$$$$Evaluating the indefinite integral, we get:
$$-\frac1{\sqrt{165}}\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{11}(2x+1)}{\sqrt{15(4x^2+4x+5)}}\right)+C$$
$$$$Now we can evaluate the integral from $0$ to $1$:
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x}{(x^2+x+4)\sqrt{4x^2+4x+5}}\ dx=$$ $$=\left[\frac1{\sqrt{11}}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{4x^2+4x+5}{11}}\right)-\frac1{\sqrt{165}}\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{11}(2x+1)}{\sqrt{15(4x^2+4x+5)}}\right)\right]_0^1=$$
$$\boxed{\frac1{\sqrt{11}}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{13}{11}}\right)-\frac1{\sqrt{165}}\tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{33}{65}}\right)-\\\frac1{\sqrt{11}}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{5}{11}}\right)+\frac1{\sqrt{165}}\tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{11}{75}}\right)}$$

---

**Question:** Is this procedure correct? Also, is there a quicker way to evaluate the integral?

Comment: If the numerical solution is not the same as your own result, you must have made a mistake somewhere

Comment: @YuriyS NIntegrate agrees with mine. But this is not the point, the main question is if there is a shorter way to this.

Comment: For your second question, Euler substitution might lead to a faster solution, though I can't say for sure until I try. See here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Euler substitution method doesn't seem to lead to a shorter solution, but still, it's quite nice.

First, we make substitution:

$$\sqrt{4x^2+4x+5}=2x+t$$

Now we find:

$$x=\frac{1}{4} \frac{5-t^2}{(t-1)}$$

And after some tedious algebra, the integral becomes:

$$2 \int_{\sqrt{5}}^{\sqrt{13}-2} \frac{(t^2-5)dt}{\left((t-1)^2+4 \right)^2+44(t-1)^2}$$

Now we make another substitution:

$$p=\frac{1}{2}(t-1)$$

And we obtain:

$$\int_{(\sqrt{5}-1)/2}^{(\sqrt{13}-3)/2} \frac{(p^2+p-1)dp}{\left(p^2+1 \right)^2+11p^2}$$

Fortunately, the denominator can be factored over real numbers, so we obtain:

> $$\int_{(\sqrt{5}-1)/2}^{(\sqrt{13}-3)/2} \frac{(p^2+p-1)dp}{\left(p^2+\frac{13}{2}- \frac{\sqrt{165}}{2}\right)\left(p^2+\frac{13}{2}+ \frac{\sqrt{165}}{2}\right)}$$

From here we use partial fractions as usual.

---

The advantage of Euler substitution and other such methods is that it's algorithmic. You can use it for any cases where the expression is a rational function of a single radical of a quadratic function. So there's no need to guess.

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes an integral involving a quadratic polynomial can be simplified a bit by letting $u$ equal to a multiple of the derivative of the quadratic.

This particular case involves two quadratics with derivatives $2x+1$ and $4(2x+1)$ suggesting a substitution $u=2x+1$ resulting in the slight reduction in the original:

$$ \int_1^3\frac{u-1}{(u^2+15)\sqrt{u^2+4}}\,du $$

Comment: I think $u=2 \sinh z$ might be a good substitution here